# Dryer (30amp) on Single Pole Breaker

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, dryer

My 200amp panel is pretty full so I started mapping all the circuits since I suspected that there are abandoned circuits or circuits with very small loads on them.
I am used to finding dryers on 30amp double pole breakers but it looks like mine is on a 30amp single pole breaker which doesnt make sense to me since it needs 240v.

Attaching a photo of the breaker & panel. The dryer is setup on the one marked (4).  Just for reference, I didnt find anything on (2) and my cooktop is setup on 6 & 8 (2x 30 amp single breakers; it turns off if either is flipped)

I just bought the house a few months back and am looking to free up some space for a finished basement.  A few circuits are setup to control 1 or 2 outlets or <4 lights.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Your photo has not posted...if you can't get it uploaded here, post it to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link to it here, then we can edit it in

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. That picture would be very helpful. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: The pictures did not attach.  Normally the "add photo" feature does work for first time posters (for photos <2MB), but if you can't find another way, slap it up on any photo sharing site and [edit] in the URLs.  SE normally uses Imgur to cache photos.

Comment: Can't wait to see your panel photos...

Comment: Does the dryer work?  It needs two hot wires from two circuits to work so another 30 amp circuit may be providing power to 1/2 the dryer needs